# Remove trailing spaces and add them as leading spaces

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to remove the trailing spaces from the expressions in my column and add them to beginning of the expression. So for instance, I currently have the expressions:

```
Sample_four_space    
Sample_two_space  
Sample_one_space
```

I would like to transform this column into:

```
    Sample_four_space
  Sample_two_space
 Sample_one_space
```

I have tried this expression:

```
UPDATE My_Table
SET name = REPLACE(name,'% ',' %')
```

However, I would like a more robust query that would work for any length of trailing spaces. Can you help me develop a query that will remove all trailing spaces and add them to the beginning of the expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know all spaces are at the end (as in your example, then you can count them and put them at the beginning:

```
select concat(space(length(name) - length(replace(name, ' ', ''))),
              replace(name, ' ', '')
             )
```

Otherwise the better solution is:

```
select concat(space( length(name) - length(trim(trailing ' ' from name)) ),
              trim(trailing ' ' from name)
             )
```

or:

```
select concat(space( length(name) - length(rtrim(name)) ),
              rtrim(name)
             )
```

Both these cases count the number of spaces (in or at the end of).  The `space()` function then replicates the spaces and `concat()` puts them at the beginning.

Comment: might be worth noting the use of replace will replace all spaces even in the middle of the string.  And the latter solution does work even if their are spaces at the beginning or middle but RTRIM() could also efficiently be used.

Comment: Right so, is there a way to do it without removing the spaces in the middle of the string?

Comment: @kbball . . . The second method.  The sample data just had spaces only at the end, so I thought of that first.

Comment: Gotcha. For some reason Trim(trailing ' '... threw an error for me, but RTRIM() did the job